# How to store a list of unknown length in an SQL database

Tags: mysql, android-sqlite

I have a table called 'Shows' that looks something like this:

`| ID | TITLE | IMG | DESC | STATUS |`

I also want to store a list of URLs that reference each Show's episode list. Unfortunately, each show can have a vastly different number of episodes, and there's no way to easily predict what the number will be for any show.

How do I store this type of data?

I considered making a table that was named after the ID of each show, with one column that contains the URLs, but I'm sure that the magic of relational databases has some other way of doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your last comment is on the right track. Yes, you need a separate table to capture the URLs, structured perhaps like:

"URL" table:

```
| UrlID | EpisodeID | URL |
```

Where "EpisodeID" is the unique identifier that you called "ID" in your table above. In other words, you might want to rename that "ID" column to "EpisodeID" to make things less confusing down the road.

This way this second "URL" table allows you to store infinite numbers of URLs associated with any single EpisodeID.

Regarding your show vs. episodes question, the same concept applies. You probably want a "Show" table separate from your "Episode" table, and then you'd add a new column to your Episode table that includes the ShowID. That way each row in "Episode" is a child whose "parent" is identified by ShowID.

Or maybe (I can't tell from your question) you expect there will never be more than one URL per episode, so you could get away with just two tables then, Show and Episode, and URL would just be a column in your Episode table.

Comment: Oh, so all the shows' episodes are jumbled up in one table, with IDs separating them. Makes sense- for some reason I was thinking they all needed to be in separate tables

Comment: Ah, right, I missed that another part of your question was about shows and episodes, so I expanded the answer.